# Adding to ArrayList from separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety

I have a program with 3 threads (excluding the main thread). The first thread moves an object across the window, the second thread checks for object collisions, and the third is supposed to add to the ArrayList of objects periodically. All three of these threads are manipulating the same list of objects (Though the first 2 are not actually changing the list, just the objects inside). However, when the thread meant to add to the list tries to add an object, I receive an error. Is it possible to manipulate an ArrayList from a different thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent the race conditions by placing the code that manipulates the array list inside `synchronized(arrayList) { ... }` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can handle the array in multiple threads. You can read more in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) about using the `synchronized` keyword with objects.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about `ArrayList` which prevents it from being read and written from multiple threads. However, note the [warning in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
> ```

It is also worth reading through the [Synchronization Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Answer (score 0):

First, If you have a multithreaded application...prefer to use something like `Vector` instead of `ArrayList` since `ArrayList` is not considered thread safe.

Also, for handling concurrency,
You can used make a `synchronized` method and perform operations to that, or use a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Java won't recognize `synchronised`--it has to be spelled `synchronized`.